# Before update trigger with flow execution

Tags: apex, flow, before-trigger

Dear reader of this question,

I have a problem using flows in conjunction with flows so that the admin can tweek the flow withouth have any apex programming skills.

I have an account **before update** trigger containing just this bit of code:

```
list<Account> accounts = newObjects;
for (Account acc: accounts) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
    params.put('Acc', acc);
    Flow.Interview.Account_update accFlow = new Flow.Interview.Account_update(params);
    accFlow.start();
    acc = (account) accFlow.getVariableValue('Acc');
    system.debug('account: ' + acc.Description);
}
```

My flow has a Sobject variable called "Acc" that is ofcourse an account.

My flow only has one assignment block that does the following:
[image: Flow assignment block]

Now here is the problem:
the code executes without having any errors but doesn't update the account value!

the result from my system.debug statement is "Account: het werkt", this leads me to conclude the assignment is done properly and since this is a before update trigger no furter action would be required...

Does anyone have any experience with doing something like this and if so, what am I doing wron or isn't possible?

Comment: Are you sure that account is updated later in your flow? Also for such purpose I often use custom settings so that admin/whoever can customize the setting and then you can grab it in your code and do what you need. As far as I remember flows are hard to debug...

Comment: is `newObjects` the same as `Trigger.new`?  I'd be looking for a binding issue between the variable `acc` that points at an object returned by `getVariableValue` that is no longer the object in `Trigger.new` and hence why nothing is updated when the trigger completes

Comment: @Oles: The flow consist only of the component shown in the picture, you can't do an update in this flow because of the before update context.

Comment: @cropredey: Yes it is the same, I was looking for this as well but since the system.debug(acc) has the right information in it (all of the old + the new info) I assumed this was fine

Comment: @Henk3000 Can you please post the full trigger code here.

Comment: @Oles: the other part of the trigger is part of a trigger manager that controles it's context but in this case just puts trigger.new into "newobjects".

Comment: @Henk3000 it looks that the only way is your assignments are mixed somewhere. Try to make sure that you work with `Trigger.new` variables.